# Solr - HTTP ERROR 500 accessing /solr/admin/. Reason: Severe errors in solr configuration

Tags: java, solr, django-haystack

Major warnings are as follows:

Solr - HTTP ERROR 500  problem accessing /solr/admin/. Reason:      Severe errors in solr configuration.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: /home/~solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example/solr/./data/index

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: /home/~solr/apache-solr-3.6.0/example/solr/./data/index

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No cores were created, please check the logs for errors

Trying to get over the first hurdle with Solr, working through the tutorial, and getting the door slammed in my face right off the bat.  Anyone have a suggestion?  Thanks.

btw, I am using java jre1.6.0_31

Comment: Solr is not able to create the index directory in the path mentioned. Check for the user and porper permission for the users to be able to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I had installed Solr in the /home dir and it was owned by root.  Java could not create directories or files.  Moved Solr to /mydir (one level below /home), now all is well.